# Cannot read property get of undefined Firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a function that will send a notification whether a document is updated.

I access the document when its updated, and I get the userId who updated that document and a status I need, after that, I just query for the user device token and send a payload, but it seems that is not working, I dont really know if there is some errors in the syntax of the code or some problems with my callbacks.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

 {service keys are initialized here}     

    exports.onOrderCreated = functions.firestore
    .document('orders/{orderId}').onUpdate(async (snap,context) => {

        var db = admin.firestore();

        try{
            const orderDataSnap = await snap.ref.get();
            var userId = orderDataSnap.data().uid;
            var orderStatus = orderDataSnap.data().status;
        }catch(error){
            return handleErrorToUser(error,snap);
        }

        let docRef = db.collection('user').doc(userId);

       return docRef.get().then(userDoc => {
           const deviceToken = userDoc.get('deviceToken')
           const payload = {
            "data": {
                "title": "Your order status here !",
                "body": "Your order status is:"+orderStatus,
                "icon": "ic_launcher",
                "sound": "default",
                "click_action": "delete_token"
              }

            }
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken,payload)
      });
    });

    // Inform about errors (these errors are for testing purposes, we should use StackDriver to log the errors 
    // to ourselves and let a friendly user error message with this function)
    async function handleErrorToUser(tError, snap) {
        console.log(tError)
      }
```

Inside orders I have to fetch this two attributes

**uid and status**

Then , with that uid, fetch the deviceToken inside user reference.

This code gives me

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>     at exports.onOrderCreated.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate (/srv/index.js:17:46)
>     at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
>     at /worker/worker.js:825:24
>     at <anonymous>
>     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

I'm not so much experienced with javascript, any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few things going wrong in here.

Firstly, the name of the first argument to your onUpdate function should probably **not** be `snap`.  As you can see in the [documentation for onUpdate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated), the first argument is a Change object that contains document snapshots for the "before" and "after" state of the document because of the update that happened.  That Change object does **not** have a property called `ref`, which is causing your code to fail.

Second, if you're expecting that this code fetch the document that was updated:

```
const orderDataSnap = await snap.ref.get();
```

That is totally not necessary here, as the contents of the document are already being delivered in Change object I mentioned before.  Just use the data you're being provided, unless you know for sure that it's not going to be what you want.

I suggest reviewing the documentation to get a better sense of how update triggers works.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in this line:

```js
const deviceToken = userDoc.get('deviceToken')
```

If 'deviceToken' token is a property from the document data, you should first run the data method, it returns all the document data properties:

```js
const deviceToken = userDoc.data().deviceToken
```